# Ejabberd authentication using Google tokens and Java API

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, ejabberd, google-authentication, smack

I am attempting to run an ejabberd server, with clients authenticating via Google 2-factor authentication (OAuth2.0).

There is a separate java application which the user will need to authenticate with first prior to connecting to ejabberd, which will authenticate a Google Token string using the method below:

```
public static GoogleIdToken authenticateToken(String inputToken){

final GsonFactory gsonFactory = new GsonFactory(); 
try {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(httpTransport, gsonFactory)
            // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
            .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID))
            .setIssuer("https://accounts.google.com")
            .build();

        // (Receive idTokenString by HTTPS POST)

        GoogleIdToken idToken;

        idToken = verifier.verify(inputToken);
        return idToken;
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception occured whilst validating Google Token...");
        return null;
    }

}
```

The ejabberd server will ideally be shut off to non-admin registrations, with one of the functions of the application described above being to register the user at ejabbered using the google Id (extracted from the idToken returned in the method above) by logging in as an admin.

The client will use Ignite Smack to create a connection using the same Google Id/ Token string that was authenticatd previously, which should then be authenticated with ejabberd in exactly the same way using the same Google authentication method. Looking through the ejabberd docs, it seems that "External Script" as mentioned in: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/authentication/ would be an ideal solution, but I am unable to get the configuration correct:

```
auth_method: [external]
extauth_program: java -cp <path_to_compiled_authentication_jar>\authentication.jar com.package.GoogleAuthenticator
```

I need to be able to execute the main method in com.package.GoogleAuthenticator class which in turn will execute the authenticateToken with the token provided by the client.

The questions I have are:
(a) Is the above a sensible approach, or are there better ways to achieve the desired outcome?
(b) What should the ejabberd config look like for this approach to work?
(c) Do the required methods exist in Smack to create a connection using a config option based on a Google Token instead of username/password?

Comment: (b) Maybe that works, but in case it doesn't, put the call in a script, make it executable, and put the full path in the config, something like: extauth_program: /full/path/to/myextscript.sh

Comment: The problem atm is that I can't find a way of (a) creating a Smack XMPPTCPConnection object using the inputToken String, and then (b) ensuring that ejabberd passes the inputToken string to the GoogleAuthenticator class main method as an arg when it is invoked